# What is the equivalent of ArcGIS's "Feature Class to Feature Class" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, feature-class

I have a layer in QGIS to which I have joined several csv tables.  I want to save this as a permanent and independent feature class.  However, when I right click on the layer in the table of content and select "Save as", and specify a new feature class, it doesn't write out some of the features.  I have discovered that the reason is because some of the fields from he csv contain entries that are over 255 characters long, and by default, the text fields that are created are initialized with a set length of 255.  Any feature that tries to write in a string longer than 255 characters fails and simply does not get written.

I found out that in ArcGIS, I can use the "Feature Class to Feature Class" tool instead of the "Export" dialog, and this tool allowed me to specify the lengths of the newly-created text fields via a field mapping.

Is there an equivalent to "Feature Class to Feature Class" in QGIS? And if so, what is it called?

Comment: If it's a table you can use a program like Excel or Access instead. What output format are you using? dbf files have a maximum of 255 characters in text fields - this is a DBaseIV limitation.

Comment: I am trying to write out to ESRI GDB.  When I did it in ArcMap, I could modify the field settings to be 500 instead.

Comment: Try with another format. SQLite, for example, should handle long field names. What are you wanting to use the written file with?

Comment: fGDB or pGDB? Text fields in pGDB can be 65535 characters as a memo type and fGDB support up to 4 billion characters. pGDB are Microsoft JET (Access) databases - generic utilities exist if you don't have Office.